# Problems reinterpreting incorrectly stored data using numpy view() function

Tags: python, numpy, casting

I have data that has been stored using an incorrect data type, and am having troubles reinterpreting the underlying data to the correct values. The data points are in reality float32 numbers which are stored as single integers (very likely 32-bit) in a system over which I have no control. What I can access are the single integers, and I would like to reinterpret them as float32 to get their correct values in Python 2. I've been using the `view()` and `neworderbytes()` functions, but are getting unexpected results.

Typical integer data is `[-2147483648, 875967683, 1005249947, 1216348160]`, which should return float numbers between -1 and +1. Those limits are not hard, so the float numbers could be slightly higher or lower but certainly not as high as 1e5, which is what I'm getting, see example below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> si = np.array([-2147483648, 0, 875967683, 1005249947, 1084227584, 1084231267, 1112226524, 1216348160], dtype=np.int32)
>>> si.view(np.float32)
array([ -0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.69692655e-07,
     7.16848439e-03,   5.00000000e+00,   5.00175619e+00,
     5.08074799e+01,   2.62144000e+05], dtype=float32)
>>> si.view(np.float32).newbyteorder()
array([  1.79366203e-43,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.80211731e+02,
    -3.80362399e-22,   5.74868682e-41,   2.63098489e+21,
    -2.09748370e+17,   4.60186416e-41], dtype=float32)
```

So, you see that the reinterpreted data doesn't fit with my expectations. Furthermore, there are some peculiarities with the distribution of the integers that intrigue me and lead me to believe that perhaps I'm doing everything right on my side but that the underlying data has been corrupted in the storing process.

Here's what I have:

```
Total number of integers            : 321,767
Number of integers = -2,147,483,648 :  91,989
Number of integers =              0 : 163,356
Number of integers >              0 :  66,422
```

So, there's a significant portion of the data that is exactly equal to -2,147,483,648, the only negative number. About half is exactly 0, which is perfectly fine and normal, and the rest is varying between 875,967,683 and 1,216,348,160 in a bit of a weird way, see plots at (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuDPc.png) in which I've sorted the data and plotted vs index, and a histogram. I expected a normal distribution in the histogram, but clearly it's not.

So, my basic question boils down to: have I used the `view()` function correctly and in the correct situation (which implies that the data is corrupt), or have I not?

Comment: I suspect that -2,147,483,648 is being used to represent `Nan`, and the rest of the numbers just need to be offset and scaled. Eg, `offset = 1 << 30; denominator = 1 << 31; floats = (si - offset) / denominator`.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, now corrected, thanks @PM2Ring! Thanks also for refining the question to define that ´view()´ is a numpy function rather than a standard Python function.

Comment: Well, -2,147,483,648 the minimum allowed value for a int32 (at least in numpy), so I agree that it makes sense for it to be a special value. `Nan` is a good idea. However, I do not believe that translation and scaling is enough, since the data is abnormally distributed, for instance with a jump between 1,092,616,192 and 1,112,226,524.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I solved it myself. My basic assumptions and expectations of the data were wrong, which is why it was so hard. Filtering out the data for one specific parameter, I found that the numpy `view` function did indeed reinterpret the underlying bytes correctly because those values I know for a fact are hard-limited to `+-0.2` and that integer data was between `950355002` and `1045220557`, which reinterpreted become:

```
>>> np.array([950355002, 1045220557], dtype=np.int32).view(np.float32)
array([  7.88052130e-05,   2.00000003e-01], dtype=float32)
```

That larger number is `0.2` when reinterpreted, which is exactly my upper hard limit. The smaller number is effectively `0`, and not the expected `-0.2`.
 Thus, I am confident that my data is incorrectly stored as int32 instead of float32 but in the process, the negative (float) data has been lost for some reason, and have most likely been stored as the default `-2,147,483,648` value.